# Shared State: Accessed by ONE thread VS MANY threads + Advanced Caching

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, vert.x, reactor

its a extension to that questions here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vertx/MmcI2dJIcRM (my posts from 08 and 20 January there)

i have State, 4 eventloop Threads/Contexts and a context to state binder

```
T state;
Context contextToStateBinder;
```

in vertx webrequests are routed in the round-robin-way to different eventloops, so

```
request 1 -> eventloop A
request 2 -> eventloop B
request 3 -> eventloop C
request 4 -> eventloop D
request 5 -> eventloop A
...
```

if i want to access from that requests the shared state i could have the following solutions:

**Solution I**

Access to state is only allowed by the same Thread/Context
So maybe i decide me for contextToStateBinder -> eventloop B context

**so each time i want to access state, i musst change the eventloop to: contextToStateBinder.runOnContext(...)**

**Solution II**

i must synchronize state: synchronized or a CAS-operation (copy state, change state, write it with CAS back, if succeed -> done, if fail-> try it again)

Both my cas/synchronized or my eventlloop switch with runOnContext (internal a mpsc-queue) have volatile reads and writes.

**So my question here: what is cheaper?**

My state there could be a game-unit/chat-room: **i guess the best way here is changing the context and not access this state by different threads, right?**

My state there could be the session-state of the users: **here Julien (vertx-project-leader) mentionend its not a good idea bind the user to a certain context (but why?, he dont justifed that till now)**
Maybe its a problem if i statically shedule different users to different contexts...... so it could be happen that one eventloop has much more requests than the other once. But if i reshedule that (rebind the user to other contests, that all context have equal much traffic), then i dont see there any problem?

**But which other problems i could get, if i do that?**

Why i guess its so powerful, binding the user to a certain eventloop thread is the following example:

**Advanced Cache:**

```
user1 -> request 1 -> eventloop A -> correct to B -> start a long-database-operation -> save the future of that operation in his state -> close the connection
user1 -> request 2 -> eventloop A -> correct to B -> want-to-recieve-the-database-result -> get the future from that state -> setTheReturn-Handler -> (maybe the result isnt yet completed) -> result-handler is executed after completion -> return the result to the user1
```

**So i dont know how i can solve that problem, if im not on the same context/eventloop: i guess if requests 1 and 2 access the state and the future from different threads, then it wont works.**

**Must i use there the same Eventloop? Or exists there a good other soultion accessing the future from different eventloops?**

you can find that question also in the vertx-forum here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vertx/m17fwSas6_0

lg knotenpunkt

Comment: If the different worker-bee threads need to see the same value then you will need to synchronize access to the cache.  But, since they are responding to web requests, I don't see any need to get complicated:  grab a semaphore of some kind, hit the cache, release the semaphore.

Comment: maybe i will edit the question and give a few more information about vertx itself: the trick of vertx is, that you dont have that much threads, only a few eventloop threads, in each context you dont need synchronization, cause no other thread can "crash in"
but yes you are true, if i use more threads to read the same global state, then i need some synchroniziaton technique. But its expensive and i dont want that. Eventloop threads are not allowed to block, else vertx isnt anymore so fast as it vertx is thought^^